# Record doesn't shows as saved

Tags: php, mysql, sanitize

This is what I do to sanitize data input via php form to database

```
function sanitize_input($data){

    global $connect;

    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = nl2br($data);
    $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data);
    return $data; 
}
```

for output

```
function sanitized_output($data){

    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    $data = strip_tags($data, '<p><a>')     ;   
    $data = str_replace(array('\r\n', '\n\r'),'',$data);
    return $data; 
}
```

There is something I am doing terribly wrong because when a paragraph is saved to the database and then retrieved, all shows up in one line.

Something like this

```
&lt;p&gt;This is paragraph 1 &lt;/p&gt;<br /><br />&lt;p&gt;This is paragraph 2 &lt;/p&gt;
```

Instead of

```
This is paragraph 1
This is paragraph 2
```

Point out the problem please.

Comment: You're doing double work. You should only escape for that what you are doing. Your sanitize_input method is a data destroying method. I wouldn't want to use this.

Comment: @VMai exactly that is what it is doing but what is the right way of sanitizing data and keeping the paragraphs and line break intact.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the **`htmlspecialchars()`** function from both of the functions.and then see the result.

Answer (score 0):

try like this you are removing all tags using all this function below

```
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
$data = strip_tags($data, '<p><a>')     ;   
$data = str_replace(array('\r\n', '\n\r'),'',$data);
```

**use this**

```
  function sanitized_output($data){

            $data = nl2br($data);
            return $data; 
        }
```

Comment: I did what you advised and this is what happens <p>This is paragraph 1</p>
\r\n
\r\n<p>This is paragraph 2</p>

Answer (score 0):

Just as a general rule, I like to do all my work when I'm saving the data. You seldom want to format the data when you're outputting it because you'll save the data once and output it multiple times.

And using `global` is another bad idea. Inject the variable into your function as an argument.

So let's rewrite the functions

```
function sanitize_input($data, $connect){
    $data = strip_tags($data, '<p><a>'); 
    $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, nl2br(trim($data)));
    return $data; 
}
```

And with that you can remove the need for `sanitized_output`. There's no need for `htmlspecialchars`

Comment: I did exactly what you said. The output now is "This is paragraph 1 \r\n \r\n This is paragraph 2".

Comment: You'll need to fix the data you put in first